# Why does my pytorch distributed training (DDP) code send a SIGKILL signal on its own?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, distributed-computing

My code runs for a few interactions but before ending the training it sends a SIGKILL for some unknown reason:

```
backend='nccl'
rank=1
mp.current_process()=<SpawnProcess name='SpawnProcess-2' parent=13950 started>
os.getpid()=13987
setting up rank=1 (with world_size=4)
MASTER_ADDR='127.0.0.1'
44109
backend='nccl'
--> done setting up rank=0
--> done setting up rank=2
--> done setting up rank=1
--> done setting up rank=3
setup process done for rank=0
setup process done for rank=2
setup process done for rank=1
setup process done for rank=3
Starting training...

n_epoch=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 279, in <module>
    main_distributed()
  File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 188, in main_distributed
    spawn_return = mp.spawn(fn=train, args=(opts,), nprocs=opts.world_size)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 199, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 157, in start_processes
    while not context.join():
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in join
    raise Exception(
Exception: process 1 terminated with signal SIGKILL
```

I don't understand why it does that. I am not incrementally storing anything as training goes so I don't think it should be a memory issue (especially if it trains fine for a few batches.

How do I even start debugging this with the error not giving me any information? Ideas?

---

In my research I've checked these links but none seem to help:

- [How does one fix a `Exception: process 0 terminated with signal SIGSEGV` error and if the single gpu code works fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268131/how-does-one-fix-a-exception-process-0-terminated-with-signal-sigsegv-error-a)
- https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3660
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/exception-process-0-terminated-with-signal-sigkill/75570/5
- https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/1590
- [Python script terminated by SIGKILL rather than throwing MemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000496/python-script-terminated-by-sigkill-rather-than-throwing-memoryerror)
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-utils-data-dataloader-issue/92770
- https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/mdsljr/why_does_my_pytorch_distributed_training_ddp_code/
- https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-does-my-PyTorch-distributed-training-DDP-code-send-a-SIGKILL-signal-on-its-own
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/54823

Comment: hey Charlie, how did you solve this?

Comment: @LeoGallucci I am not sure if I did. But perhaps make sure that you don't have a process using a lot of space. At one point I remember opening a lot of files by accident in the dataloader and that screwed me up. Perhaps see my other related questions/answers on DDP and gpu issues you might find something there.