# Setting number of threads in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-multithreading, intel-mkl

I have a python script which consist of numpy and scipy functions. I was trying to check the scaling for my code.

```
numpy.show_config()
```

The configuration for the numpy installed in my system shows the following information.

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['Library\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['Library\\include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['Library\\include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['Library\\include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2,AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL
    not found =
```

So I tried setting the following environment variables **before importing numpy**:

```
import os    
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = '16' 
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = '16' 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = '16'
```

But still, my code is only using 1 thread and there is not difference in the time of execution of the program.

I have also tried setting `mkl.set_num_threads(16)` but no difference.

I am aware that python has GIL which doesn't allow multiple threads to execute simultaneously as u expect in C. Is there any other way to set the number of threads to be used in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but you have to set the environment variables before the first time you load a module in your script (including any the sub modules)

To be safe you should do this in your main program before any other import

```py
import os
nthreads = 1
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = str(nthreads) 
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = str(nthreads) 
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = str(nthreads)
import numpy
```

An alternative is to set the environment variables before running the script as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622299/12750353).

One thing I thought was that reloading the module using import lib could do the trick to allow setting it dynamically, but no, it doesn't work.

If you are can use [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) instead of [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) then you may use [torch.set_num_threads](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_num_threads.html?highlight=set_num_threads#torch.set_num_threads) that is effective, check an example usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030518/12750353).